# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert while buy token

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, evm, nodejs

I built a token based on ERC20, when I try to buy tokens I get this error

In the truffle console

```js
Quinn.deployed().then(function(ins){token=ins}) QuinnSale.deployed().then(function(ins){tokenSale = ins})

const acc = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

tokenSale.buyTokens(1,{from:acc[1],value:1000000000000000,gas:500000})
```

Note: token price is 0.001 eth, this acc[1] has enough eth, token sale address has allowance

here is the code of the contracts

**quinn.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Quinn {
    string public name = "Quinn";
    string public symbol = "QNN";
    string public standard = "QNN v1.0";

    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // transfer event
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    // approve event
    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
        totalSupply = _initialSupply; // 1 million
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    }

    //transfer
    //Exception if account does not have enough
    //return a boolen
    //transfer event
    function transfer(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        // trigger the transfer event
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    //delegated transfer

    // approve transfer
    function approve(
        address _spender,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        // allowance
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        // approve event
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    // transfer from
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        // require _from has enough tokens
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);

        // require  allowance is big enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        // transfer event
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        // change the balanceOf address
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;

        // update the balanceOf address
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        // update the allowance of address
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**quinnsale.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "./Quinn.sol";

contract QuinnSale {
    // DO NOT expose the address of admin
    address admin;
    Quinn public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor(Quinn _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) {
        // Assign an admin
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    // mulitply
    //pure means not create transactions, not read or write data to blockchain
    function multiply(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
        // ensuring that after multiplication, returned value is not getting overflowed.
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    // Buy tokens
    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        // require that value is equal to tokens
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        // require that the contract has enough tokens
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(admin) >= _numberOfTokens);
        // msg.sender here is the buyer
        // in transfer function, msg.sender is QuinnSale contract
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why i am facing this error please help :(

Comment: Try putting messages on your require statements to see if one of them is causing the revert.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem could be that you are checking the balance of the `admin` account, but transfering tokens from the sale contract.

```
    // require that the contract has enough tokens
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(admin) >= _numberOfTokens);
    // msg.sender here is the buyer
    // in transfer function, msg.sender is QuinnSale contract
    require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));
```

Either transfer tokens availables for sell to the sale contract, or the admin has to approve the sale contract and use `transferFrom` on the sale contract.